# Is there any way for a Magus to get Dance of a Hundred Cuts added to his spell list?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magus

[Dance of a Hundred Cuts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dance-of-a-hundred-cuts/) is a level 4 spell for bards only. You would think this spell would be perfect for a magus with the Dervish Dance feat.

Is it possible for a magus to learn or cast this spell?  And if so, how?

Comment: oh no just a dervish that uses the dervish dance feat so...most of em.

Answer (score 7):

A [Samsaran](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-samsaran/) is able to take the Mystic Past Lives alternate racial trait:

> Mystic Past Life (Su) You can add spells from another spellcasting class to the spell list of your current spellcasting class. You add a number of spells equal to 1 + your spellcasting class’s key ability score bonus (Wisdom for clerics, and so on). The spells must be the same type (arcane or divine) as the spellcasting class you’re adding them to. For example, you could add divine power to your druid class spell list, but not to your wizard class spell list because divine power is a divine spell. These spells do not have to be spells you can cast as a 1st-level character. The number of spells granted by this ability is set at 1st level. Changes to your ability score do not change the number of spells gained. This racial trait replaces shards of the past.

Answer (score 2):

There's a third party Magus Arcana [Harmonic Blending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/super-genius-games-magus-arcana/harmonic-blending-ex/) from Super Genius Games.

> Benefit: When a magus selects this arcana, he must select one spell from the bard spell list that is at least one level lower than the highest magus spell level he can cast. He adds this spell to his spellbook and list of magus spells known as a magus spell one level higher than its bard spell level. He can instead select two spells to add in this way, but both must be at least two levels lower than the highest-level magus spell he can cast.

This is similar to [Spell Blending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/spell-blending-ex/) from Paizo except the bard spell must be at least 1 level lower than your highest spell level.